# Display Pycaret graphs on Azure Notebooks

Tags: azure, matplotlib, plot, databricks, pycaret

Pycaret has some rich functions to plot metrics for the models. In the docs, they use jupyter notebooks and it runs perfectly. I'm using Azure Notebooks and I'm not able to display the graphs.

My code is as below:

`plot_model(tuned_model)`

output: IntProgress(value=0, description='Processing: ', max=5)

I've also tried to use display, like this:
`display(plot_model(tuned_model))`

But it returns the same output, not showing up any graph.

When I've tried to show other graphs, **not from pycaret**, it runs normally as below: (Graph shows up after that)

```
plt.xlabel('date')
plt.ylabel('sales')
plt.plot(train.index,train['sessoes'],label='train')
plt.plot(test.index,test['sessoes'],label='test')
plt.legend()
display(plt.show())
```

In this link you can check some examples of what I'm trying to plot (Cell 24):

https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/blob/master/examples/TimeSeries_Forecasting.ipynb

Does anyone knows how to show up pycaret graphs on Azure notebooks?

Comment: any update on the solution ???